# Is there any way to Protect Document Directory in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there any way to Protect Document Directory in IOS. Any other can not show it's data via any other software? Any encrypted method Or Password Protected for we can protect Data.

My Application is related to Music App. In My app we download songs in Document Directory.

Any user can listen songs via my application. but they can not access that song via any software. 
For ex. If we use iFunbox From Mac we can get every data. We don't want to access my data from that kind of software.

Any way to protect my data?

Comment: Maybe learning about the [directories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)  and which is available for the user to see would help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to encrypt an entire directory on iOS devices but you could take a look at RNCryptor to encrypt the songs that your app downloads.

[RNCryptor - Github](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor)

You can user it to enrypt the songs individually and decrypt the data before you play them in your app.